# Can you create a boxplot for Blood Pressure vs Specific Ages (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

For my project I am using a matlab sample dataset called hospital.mat and am trying to create a boxplot for Blood Pressure vs specific age ranges (shown below). When I attempted to create a boxplot I received an error saying Matrix dimensions must agree. I believe this may be because the data for Blood Pressure is measuring both systolic and diastolic (which is good) OR because it is gathering the complete data for patients of all ages when I am only looking for the blood pressure of a specific age range.

The matrix for hospital.Age is 100 x 1 double and the matrix for hospital.BloodPressure is 100 x 2 double

```
load hospital.mat %Sample data provided by matlab
x=hospital.Age;
x(hospital.Age<35,:)=-1;
x(hospital.Age>=35 & hospital.Age<45)=-2;
x(hospital.Age>=45)=-3;
boxplot(hospital.BloodPressure==x(hospital.Age<35,:),x(hospital.Age<35,:));
```

Any help would be great! Thank you.

Comment: The matrix for hospital.Age is 100 x 1 double
and the matrix for hospital.BloodPressure is 100 x 2 double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the values you set as grouping variables in your dataset `hospital`. The second argument of `boxplot` is a grouping variable, which can be anything, so in your case this can be the 'age labels'.

I took the `abs` of these labels, to make sure that the boxplots are increasing in age from left to right.

```
load hospital.mat %Sample data provided by matlab

x = hospital.Age;
x(hospital.Age<35,:) = -1;
x(hospital.Age>=35 & hospital.Age<45) = -2;
x(hospital.Age>=45) = -3;

% store labels in data set to use as grouping variable
hospital.AgeLabels = x;

% create the figure
figure()
ax(1) = subplot(121);
boxplot(hospital.BloodPressure(:,1), abs(hospital.AgeLabels))
title('BloodPressure 1')

ax(2) = subplot(122);
boxplot(hospital.BloodPressure(:,2), abs(hospital.AgeLabels))
title('BloodPressure 2')

% set meaningfull ticklabels for both subplots
for ii = 1:2
    ax(ii).XTickLabels = {'<35', '>=35 & <45', '>= 45'};
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it! Your work was very clear and easy for me to understand!